# how to change position of bottomappbar notch in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I try to use default position of notch FloatingActionButton but FloatingActionButton just have three position (startDocked, endDocked and centerDocked) but I need to add notch between center and left or center and right like below picture.

[flutter FloatingActionButton notch position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSzkM.jpg)

how i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your FloatingActionButton with Padding to shift position:

```
floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.remove),
          onPressed: () => null,
        ),
      ),
```